# How to group by with a having clause in gridDB?

Tags: griddb

Is there a way or what is the equivalent of group by with having clause in GridDB when compared to RDBMS?

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](https://griddb.org/docs-en/manuals/GridDB_SQL_Reference.html)? That's where you should start. When you have specific problems, then come here for specific help.